# Pie chart with grayed out areas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I want to create a pie chart, that looks pretty much like that one:

[image]

I already tried pgf-pie to recreate it, but without any success. my result is far from what it should look like.

However, I need something like a piechart, but with grayed out areas like in the picture and a point, that is pointing on a specific area. 
Can somebody help me to get on the right track?

Comment: Why not post the code you tried but didn't work? People around here often like to have something to start with. If you're lucky, someone will also give you some advices about why your code wasn't working the way you wanted it to.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.StackExchange! You have just been asked to write a minimal example. [What is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/31685). [What makes a good minimal example?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/31685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);

\foreach \i/\j in {0/5mm,45/2mm,90/4mm,135/3mm,180/1mm,270/2mm}
    \draw[line width=\j, gray] (\i:1.5) arc[start angle=\i, delta angle=45, radius=1.5cm];

\foreach \i in {0,45,...,360}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(\i:1.5);

\fill (25:5mm) circle (.5mm); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome i looks exactly that way i need it. Big tanks